# How do I know who is making a request to my Amazon API Gateway endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to tell who is making a request to my integration.

Say I set up api key "123abc" and give it to Bob. My API method requires a key, so Bob dutifully includes it in the header of his request (x-api-key=123abc). Bob is able to successfully reach my endpoint, but my integration has no idea if the person who made the request is Bob (123abc) or Doug (456def) or Suzy (789ghi).

It seems Gateway does not pass the api key along with the request. The integration has business logic that must be respected, based on who makes a request. So I need to know which api key was used, or have some other way of associating a request with a person. I don't see any other identifying traits in the request headers or body (except perhaps X-Amzn-Trace-Id?). I've read countless articles and googled all manner of phrases. Maybe I'm missing some high level concept that would illuminate my search. Please enlighten me.

Comment: I could have been clearer about what I'm trying to accomplish. I simply want Gateway to pass along the api key that the client is using to authenticate, rather than stripping out all identifiers before the request gets to my integration. I will handle associating the api key (123abc) with a known entity (Bob) myself. See my answer for the workflow I stumbled upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after poking at it for long enough. In a resource's method execution, you can set up certain headers to be passed through the request lifecycle.

In the relevant Method Request (e.g. "/pets" POST), go to the HTTP Request Headers section. Click "+ Add header" and type the name of the header that the client is providing (in my case `x-api-key`). Optionally mark it as required. Next, go back to Integration Request and under the (similar) HTTP Headers section click add a header. Give it a name and map it to the header from the previous step (I called mine `apikey` and mapped it from `method.request.header.x-api-key`). Now my integration can know that when it gets a request with header apikey=123abc, that's good ole Bob!

This is for an HTTP-based REST API btw. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So AWS API Gateways have support for something called *custom authorizer*.

**What is custom athorizer?**
It is just a door keeper lambda that will show allow/deny for each request.
[image]
This lambda gets `methodArn` as an argument and you can call `denyAll` or `allowAll` on this `methodArn` to get `AuthPolicy`.
Once you get the `AuthPolicy` you can set the api key or you can even get the policy context and add your own key value pairs.  You also get the api-key as an input parameter with name `authorizationToken`

```
AuthPolicy authPolicy = methodArn.allowAll(subject);
authPolicy.setUsageIdentifierKey(apiKey);

Map<String, Object> context = authPolicy.getContext();
if (context == null) {
  context = new HashMap<>();
}

context.put("myownkey", "myownvalue");
```

---

Then from the target lambda you can do this to read the values from the request (`APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent`):

```
Map<String, Object> authContext = request.getRequestContext().getAuthorizer();
String subject = (String) authContext.getOrDefault("myownkey", "");
```

You can do more with custom authorizers, here is the AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html).